# Styling an expanding button's hover-state

Tags: css

I've made a button that expands horizontally: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/TsDud/

However I'm having a hard time getting my button's hover-state to work properly.

This is my markup:

```
<a class="action-button" href="#"><span>Some text</span></a>
```

I don't know how to style the hover-effect so that the entire button is "lit" when the user hovers over a part of the button that isn't covered by the `<span>`.

This is what I get when I hover over a part of the button that isn't covered by the `<span>`:

[image]

Check out my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/TsDud/

Comment: What do you mean by expanding?

Comment: (beautiful button I assume you're a web designer! :) ) I'd suggest you to load only one .png image, inside this image put all your :hover selected and all other button designs, than use `background-position` to 'change' the image for your button states. It will load only one image that will be cached by the browser. Doing so you'll preserve the 'hover image loading time' avoiding the button to disappear until the hover image is loaded.

Comment: To be honest, I like more the 'final' :hover state like in the image you provided! :) it's more 'fancy' and 'unusual'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/TsDud/5/)**

Change the last lines to:

```
a.action-button:hover > span
```

Ex:

```
a.action-button:hover > span{
    background: transparent url(http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/228089/action-button-left-hover.png) no-repeat;
    color: white;
}
```

And as I said in the comment above try to avoid to use *separate* images for your button states.

Use only one image and for ex. on *hover* just 'change' the `background-position` to the part of image representing the state you want!
It will save you the "button disappearance" until the new image is loaded.

Comment: Thx for helping me out :) I'm definitely going to use your background-positioning trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the hover rule to only be for `a.action-button`  At present you have the style rule for both a.action-button and its span.

```
a.action-button:hover { ...
```

and

```
a.action-button span:hover { ....
```

Instead try applying it this way:

```
a.action-button:hover { ...
```

and

```
a.action-button:hover span { ...
```

won't work on some older version of IE however.

http://jsfiddle.net/HZpDL/